# React Native & Firebase | Cannot sort data received by firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

```js
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "posts"));
```

Need to order querySnapshot by 'eventdate' and in 'desc' order.

```js
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "posts", orderBy('eventDate', 'desc')))
```

Have attempted to implement this way but no success, the entries on firebase just stopped loading.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're missing a composite index that is needed for the query (ascending and descending order are different indexes).

To troubleshoot and fix this:

1. Catch and log any errors that are thrown
2. Check in the error message for a URL.
3. Click that URL and it'll take you to the Firestore console to create the index that is needed for the query.

Answer (score 0):

Let start data as current time and compare it with your time field as i did
, then orderBy it in desc formate as you needed

it is **Firebase FireStore-Cloud** Excercise which i was performed some days back
but if you are using firebase **RealtimeDataBase** Then just syntax will change otherthan logic will same.

```html
let start = Date.now();

    try {
      await firestore()
        .collection(DB_Name.all_requests)
        .where('timeStamp', "<=", start)
        .limit(newcount)
        .orderBy('timeStamp', 'desc')
        .get()
        .then(async querySnap => {
          //You will data here
          })
         .catch(e=>console.log('error',e)
       
       }catch(err){
         console.log("error in fetching",err)
         }
```